# VTK configuration issue on Mac with Cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, vtk

Error in Cmake configuration for VTK

I am a beginner building the lib environment for ITK/VTK/QT for medical imaging analysis. The problem comes in when try to install VTK.

1. On my OSX 10.14.5, I already installed QT5 with brew install.
2. make install the ITK lib successful and tested it without VTK.
3. In the Cmake interface, I configure the correct qt5 path for vtk and start the configuration. But there is error happened after a while. Part of the error information showed as following.

I am not sure this error is linked to qt or other dependency? Is it the problem of the OpenGL2 or others?

I would be very appreciated if you could help me through this issue.

```
Group Qt modules:
vtkGUISupportQt;vtkGUISupportQtSQL;vtkRenderingQt;vtkViewsQt
Group Rendering modules:
vtkGeovisCore;vtkIOExport;vtkIOExportPDF;vtkInteractionImage;vtkInteractionStyle;vtkInteractionWidgets;vtkRenderingAnnotation;vtkRenderingContext2D;vtkRenderingCore;vtkRenderingFreeType;vtkRenderingImage;vtkRenderingLOD;vtkRenderingLabel;vtkRenderingVolume;vtkViewsContext2D;vtkViewsCore;vtkViewsInfovis Group Tk modules: vtkRenderingTk Group Views modules: vtkViewsContext2D;vtkViewsGeovis Group Web modules: vtkWebCore;vtkWebPython;vtkWebGLExporter Backend OpenGL2 modules: vtkDomainsChemistryOpenGL2;vtkIOExportOpenGL2;vtkImagingOpenGL2;vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2;vtkRenderingGL2PSOpenGL2;vtkRenderingLICOpenGL2;vtkRenderingOpenGL2;vtkRenderingOpenVR;vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL2

Enabling modules for OpenGL2.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:156 (export):
  export EXPORT or TARGETS specifier missing.

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/morse/VTK-8.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/morse/VTK-8.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: @HoloLady: Please, do not format error logs and the logs of other types as a *blockquote*. This formatting doesn't preserve newlines, so the logs becomes harder to read. Use **code** formatting instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

Open CMakeList.txt and modify as following,
Cut and paste lines from 156~157 to 154~155.
Final code like this :

```
# Add a virtual target that can be used to build all compile tools.
add_custom_target(vtkCompileTools)
if (_vtk_compiletools_targets)
  list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES _vtk_compiletools_targets)
  export(TARGETS ${_vtk_compiletools_targets}
    FILE ${VTK_BINARY_DIR}/VTKCompileToolsConfig.cmake)
  add_dependencies(vtkCompileTools ${_vtk_compiletools_targets})
endif()

unset(_vtk_targets)
unset(_vtk_compiletools_targets)
unset(_vtk_all_targets)
```

Good luck~!

Comment: I also had this problem on Windows10, VTK 8.2, CMake 3.15.0 (VS 2019 generator) and this solution worked for me

Comment: Hi Allorong, your answer almost solve the problem, except one.

It is okay to go through the cmake and generate after modify the cmakelist.txt in the source file. And it is okay then use "make" in the terminal for the build file. 

But when I use "make install", 1 error happen as following:

CMake Error at GUISupport/Qt/PluginInstall.cmake:21 (file):
  file cannot create directory: /usr/local/plugins/designer.  Maybe need
  administrative privileges.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  GUISupport/Qt/cmake_install.cmake:91 (include)
  cmake_install.cmake:160 (include)